# Magento2.3.1 : multiselect attribute values is not saving for products via magento backend

Tags: magento2.3, import, multiselect-attribute

I have tried to save multiple values of an attribute for a product, but it is not saving.

I have used Pipe separator and comma separator, unfortunately, both are not working

Please find my csv file here
[image]

Comment: did you get any error in file check or import ?

Comment: No the file imported successfully, but the values are not saved

Comment: What is a size of that attribute?

Comment: I have changed the attribute backend type from "varchar"  to "text", then it uploading values as expected

Answer (score 0):

The backend type of the attribute is "varchar", this type having memory limitations so my values are not updated as expected. Once changed it from "varchar" to "text" it works